# Как записывать сессию PHP при первом посещении и последующем использовании?

Tags: php, сессия

Например, пользователь первый раз пришел на сайт с определенного УРЛ, мне необходимо записать урл в сессию, даже если пользователь обновит страницу или перейдет на другую страницу.
Мне удается только получить урл, но не записать за пользователем:

```
            session_start();

            $source_session = $_SESSION["origURL"];

            if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) ) {
              $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
              $source_session = $_SESSION["origURL"];
            }
```

Comment: достаточно ее после ифа написать, а из тела ифа убрать вообще.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["origURL"])) $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
              
$source_session = $_SESSION["origURL"];
```

Comment: как вы написали в комментарии, варнинг не повлияет на запись данных в сессию. Он будет выведен, но данные то все равно впишутся.

Comment: @teran понял, думал из за первой ошибки возможно не записывало в сессию. Тут еще не понятно что конкретно нужно, вроде код должен срабатывать, если что то другие в него не вмешивается

Comment: возможно, там просто до старта сессии что-то выводится, и она попросту не стартует.

Comment: Попадает из поисковика на сайт, ваш код верно запишет УРЛ откуда пришел,  но стоит пользователю по ходить по внутренним страницам сайта, так урл меняется на тот, что по сайту проходит.